# How to add different highcharts theme to different charts

Tags: highcharts

I want to add different highcharts theme to different charts which are defined within a variable. I am trying to add Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme1) inside the charts defined within a variable but it is not showing the chart if i am doing this.

Comment: I want something like this

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme1);
});

Comment: The theme is applied for all charts in the same webpage.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I want to add a particular theme to a particular chart only, can we do something in this way ?

Comment: At this moment this is not possible, you can post your suggestion in our uservoice [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com)